# Bootstrap modal is not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using  Bootstrap v3.0.1  and jquery-1.11.0 and I have an issue with the Bootstrap modal that is not showing correctly.

**Html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This viewed like this:

[image]

Comment: all the markup please? and stylesheet? and jsfiddle/codepen/plunker demo?

Comment: It won't work well, if it is in an iframe.

Comment: Put your modal `HTML` End of body.

Comment: $('#bt1').click(function(){$('#myModal').modal('show')});

Comment: All are not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Check you have jquery 1.9.0 or higher. This modal works for me.

```
<div class="modal" id="modalEx">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
            Content Part goes here...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Event Calling Part:

```
$('#modalLaunch').click(function(){
 $('#modalEx').modal({show:true})
});
```

Comment: I am using jquery-1.11.0

Answer (score 1):

It *does* shows correctly, however it doesn't work as you *would like to*. If I see it correctly, you want to make a modal window, which appears in the parent frame. This will not work, plain and simple.

The modal window should originate from the parent frame, then it will work as you would like to.